# How to mix encoded and non-encoded scripts?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a password generator, for personnal usage:

Currently I have :

```
if ( $argumentsNonValid ){ exit }

# different parameters for the generation
$setting1= 3
$setting2= 7
$setting3=13
$setting4=77

$trim=$args[0].ToUpper()
```

This is the start of my script then, I want to hide it so I encoded it in Base64

but since I required the use of $args[0], (that disapear in the next session), except by puting it into a txt file and then read it, I don't know how to pass it to :

```
PowerShell.exe -EncodedCommand "......."
```

The -args param is not valid with -EncodedCommand

At the end I would like something like this :

```
if ( $argumentsNonValid ){ exit }

# different parameters for the generation
$setting1= 3
$setting2= 7
$setting3=13
$setting4=77

$trim=$args[0].ToUpper()

USAGE OF ENCODED STRING
```

Is it possible ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the requirement, and this is too long to post in comments. At this time, this is not an answer; but I would like to know if this helps or pushes us in the right direction.

```
# $command contains all of the code you want encoded including the argument

$command = @'
function test {
"your argument is $($args[0])"
}
test something
'@

$encodedcommand = [convert]::toBase64String([text.encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))

# Output
powershell.exe -encodedcommand $encodedcommand
your argument is something
```

This demonstrates that `$args` is not lost when a command is encoded. But I need help understanding how to proceed further with your issues.

It seems like this would be better suited for a module. Then you can create functions that you can make private or hidden.

Comment: I have a very long function, will it work ? But yes it helps a lot thanks !